# Trigonometry problem involving vectors

Tags: trigonometry

An airplane is headed 123 degrees with an air speed of 310 mph with a wind of 40 mph on a bearing of 200 degrees. Find the ground speed to the nearest mph, and the true course of the airplane to the nearest degree.

I tried to draw the vectors but I am unable to figure it out.Please help me.